# CMS automation in VBA stalls after 63 iterations

Tags: vba, automation, avaya

I am writing an automation script as I have a need to run a report on 16 separate split skills each day for a period of 6 months.  The script works, with one problem.   It will run 63 iterations (i.e. 3 days at 16 = 48 + 15 = 63).   After the 15th loop (63rd overall iteration) it will give an error: "microsoft excel is waiting for another application to complete an OLE action"   It would appear to me, though I could very easily be wrong, that either I am overloading a variable or possibly not fully closing something on the CMS side.   The fact that it is the 63rd iteration (64-1) seems awfully suspicious, but I am not sure what I could be overloading as far as variables going.   I don't have any 8-bit variables (unless I am missing something).  Also, I should point out that after running the macro, I am uanble to log back into the CMS app manually without restarting, so my hunch is that I am not fully closing something and that maybe there is a limit on the number of instances allowed in CMS.   I included the script below, except that the names of the skills, server address, username and password have been removed for security reasons.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
Public Sub Single_CMS_Report_Extract()

On Error Resume Next

' Add the files specified below to the References section:
' Tools -> References -> Browse to the CMS directory,
' e.g.: "C:\Program Files\Avaya\CMS Supervisor R14"
Dim cmsApplication As ACSUP.cvsApplication 'acsApp.exe
Dim cmsServer As ACSUPSRV.cvsServer 'acsSRV.exe
Dim cmsConnection As ACSCN.cvsConnection 'cvsconn.dll
Dim cmsCatalog As ACSCTLG.cvsCatalog 'cvsctlg.dll
Dim cmsReport As Object 'ACSREP.cvsReport 'acsRep.exe

Dim myLog As String, myPass As String, myServer As String
Dim reportPath As String, reportName As String, reportPrompt(1 To 2, 1 To 3) As String
Dim exportPath As String, exportName As String

Dim StartRunTime, EndRunTime As Date

Dim DayToRun, EndDate As Date
Dim Skill(1 To 16) As String

MsgBox ("Please ensure CMS open and logged in prior to continuing")
StartRunTime = Now

'Start Date
DayToRun = "12/16/2015"
'End Date
EndDate = "12/21/2015"



Skill(1) = "XXXXXXXX"
Skill(2) = "XXXXXXXX"
Skill(3) = "XXXXXXXX"
Skill(4) = "XXXXXXXX"
Skill(5) = "XXXXXXXX"
Skill(6) = "XXXXXXXX"
Skill(7) = "XXXXXXXX"
Skill(8) = "XXXXXXXX"
Skill(9) = "XXXXXXXX"
Skill(10) = "XXXXXXXX"
Skill(11) = "XXXXXXXX"
Skill(12) = "XXXXXXXX"
Skill(13) = "XXXXXXXX"
Skill(14) = "XXXXXXXX"
Skill(15) = "XXXXXXXX"
Skill(16) = "XXXXXXXX"

While DayToRun < (EndDate + 1)




    For i = 1 To 16

        ' Assigns Variables
        myLog = "myuser"
        myPass = "mypass"
        myServer = "xx.xx.xx.xx"
        'reportPath is the tab and "Category" that the report is found in Avaya
        reportPath = "Historical\Split/Skill\"
        reportName = "Summary Interval"

        'list of input names requested.....
        reportPrompt(1, 1) = "Split/Skill"
        reportPrompt(1, 2) = "Date"
        reportPrompt(1, 3) = "Times"

        'list of responses being used for input
        reportPrompt(2, 1) = Skill(i)
        reportPrompt(2, 2) = DayToRun
        reportPrompt(2, 3) = "00:00-23:30"

        'path and name of exported report file
        exportPath = "H:\Avaya data\"
        If i <> 5 Then
            exportName = Month(DayToRun) & "-" & Day(DayToRun) & "-" & Skill(i) & ".csv"
        Else
            exportName = Month(DayToRun) & "-" & Day(DayToRun) & "- DL-Toll Free" & ".csv"
        End If

        ' Open the CMS Application, launches acsApp.exe
        ' If a CMS Supervisor console is already open,
        ' the existing acsApp.exe is used.
        Set cmsApplication = CreateObject("ACSUP.cvsApplication")
        Set cmsServer = CreateObject("ACSUPSRV.cvsServer")
        Set cmsConnection = CreateObject("ACSCN.cvsConnection")
        cmsConnection.bAutoRetry = True

        ' Connetsc to the server, launches acsSRV.exe & ACSTrans.exe (2x)
        If cmsApplication.CreateServer(myLog, myPass, "", myServer, False, "ENU", cmsServer, cmsConnection) Then
        If cmsConnection.login(myLog, myPass, myServer, "ENU", "", False) Then
        End If
        End If

        ' Gets collection of Reports available on cmsServer
        Set cmsCatalog = cmsServer.Reports
        If cmsServer.Connected = False Then cmsServer.Reports.ACD = 1

        ' Sets parameters for report, launches ACSRep.exe (2x)
        cmsCatalog.CreateReport cmsCatalog.Reports.Item(reportPath & reportName), cmsReport



        If cmsReport.SetProperty(reportPrompt(1, 1), reportPrompt(2, 1)) And cmsReport.SetProperty(reportPrompt(1, 2), reportPrompt(2, 2)) And cmsReport.SetProperty(reportPrompt(1, 3), reportPrompt(2, 3)) Then
        End If

        ' Runs report and extracts results  --- the 44 is the field delimiter
        cmsReport.ExportData exportPath & exportName, 44, 0, False, False, True


        ' Kills active report & server
        If Not cmsServer.Interactive Then
        cmsServer.ActiveTasks.Remove cmsReport.TaskID
        cmsApplication.Servers.Remove cmsServer.ServerKey
        End If

        ' Logs out
        cmsReport.Quit
        cmsConnection.Logout
        cmsConnection.Disconnect
        cmsServer.Connected = False

        ' Releases objects
        Set cmsReport = Nothing
        Set cmsCatalog = Nothing
        Set cmsConnection = Nothing
        Set cmsServer = Nothing
        Set cmsApplication = Nothing


    Next
    i = Nothing
    DayToRun = DateAdd("d", 1, DayToRun)
    Wend

EndRunTime = Now
MsgBox ("Run-time = " & Minute(EndRunTime - StartRunTime) & ":" & Second(EndRunTime - StartRunTime))

End Sub
```

Comment: I have not actually solved the problem.   I have worked around it thus far, but would really love to have a more permanent solution.   I have found that if I run 3 days worth or reports, exit Excel and exit Avaya, then reopen Avaya, sign back in, then reopen Excel, I can repeat this process over and over.   Still, not quite what I want.   I tried to move the loop in so that I could reuse the same objects without constantly creating and destroying the objects, but then it would only spit out a maximum of 4 results or sometimes 12 and I could not figure out why for the life of me.

Comment: I also tried it, I have a loop that opens and closes the CMS every 10 interactions, managed to keep a reasonable stability, however still hangs sometimes =( . (Sorry for the poorly english)

Comment: When you say you open and close the CMS every 10 interactions, do you mean the CMS server, application. connection or all of them?   Would it be possible for you to share your code (removing your personal info like username and password, of course)?

Comment: @Fred if you are still in need of this I could give you some piece of my code that works this out.